# Nodejs only can send message to owner message sender

Tags: javascript, node.js

You suppose we have two registered user as User1 and User2 and both of them logged into system, now User1 want to send message to User2, after send message to him, my nodejs server said User2 not connected, and when User2 want to send message to User1 i get this notify which User1 not connected, but both of them users are connected,

now

- User1 only can send message to himself
- User2 only can send message to himself

but they could not send message to other users

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();

var io_redis    = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(io_redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

var options = {
    workers     : require('os').cpus().length,
    first_port  : 8000,
    proxy_port  : 3000,
    session_hash: function (req, res) {
        return req.connection.remoteAddress;
    },

    no_sockets: false
};

require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.on('login', function (data) {
            console.log(data.username);
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
                if (success) {
                    redisClient.exists(data.username, function (err, doesExist) {
                        if (err) return;

                        if (!doesExist) {
                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            redisClient.del(data.username);
                            redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, res) {
                                redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id);
                            });
                        }

                    });
                    socket.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
                } else {
                    socket.emit('login', {result: false});
                }
            });
        });

        socket.on('requestMoney', function (data) {

            redisClient.get(data.fromUsername, function (err, socketId) {
                if (io.sockets.connected[socketId]) {
                    log.info('message to '+ data.fromUsername + ' sent');
                    io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', {message: 'Hey !!'});
                } else {
                    log.info(data.fromUsername + ' NOT Login');
                }
            });

        });
    });

    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
    });
}
```

Comment: @Tom oh man!! whats problem in your case?

Answer (score 1):

## Problem resolved

instead of

```
io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit(''));
```

i use this code:

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketId).emit(''));
```

now i can send message to specific user from web to android logged user and from android device to web logged user

My Html test code to anybody whom want to learn more that about that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>
        Document
    </title>
    </meta>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#login').click(function () {
                socket.emit('login', {username: 'mahdi', password: 'a'});
            });

            $('#mesage').click(function () {
                socket.emit('requestMoney', {fromUsername: 'a'});
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        var socket = new io.connect('http://192.168.1.35:3000', {
            transports: ['websocket']
        });
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('connected!');
        });
        socket.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log("hello ::::::::" + message);
        });
        socket.on('success', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h3 id="login">login</h3>

<h3 id="mesage">mesage</h3>
</body>
</html>
```